# How to convert Excel 2007 Open XML (*.xlsx) to legacy format files (*.xls, ex. Excel 97) using Softartisans ExcelWriter

Tags: c#, .net, excel, officewriter

Is there a way to convert between the new Excel 2007/2010/2013 (*.xlsx) file format and the old pre-2007 (*.xls) format using the Softartisans ExcelWriter .NET library.

This code:

```
ExcelApplication application = new ExcelApplication();
Workbook workbook = application.Open("NewFormatFile.xlsx");
application.Save(workbook, "OldFormatFile.xls");
```

gives following error:

```
This workbook is a workbook without macros and must be saved with the .xlsx extension, but filename was OldFormatFile.xls
```

Comment: If it's a simple workbook, you can use the Interop assembly and save it in the .xls format. But I am not sure if that would work for Macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot convert xlsx to xls with ExcelApplication or ExcelTemplate.

This is noted in the Template object Open() method documentation, and the same applies for the application object:

http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/ExcelTemplate.Open(System.IO.Stream)

Comment: Thanks, I've only looked at the ExcelApplication object as I was not interested in templating.

Comment: No problem, I will see to it that the documentation is updated.